# Not able to create new variable and send as udp in the same socket

Tags: python-3.x, udp

I am trying to send some data from android to python server then want to run some functions and send the data back to android. Android code is working fine, but my program ignore the lines where I am creating new variables and sending the data. I am using python3.
The particular line is num = random.randint(1,100)

```
serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSock.bind(("", UDP_PORT))

def userrec(addr):
  num = random.randint(1,100)
  result = num.encode("utf-8")
  serverSock.sendto(result, addr)


while True:
  data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(1024)
  message = data.decode("utf-8")
  if data:
    userrec(addr)
serverSock.close()
```

Can't we create new variables or run some function after recieving the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I just have to remove ServerSock.close()